# Как можно проверить String Name в конструкторе и исключить ввод неправильных значений пользователем?

Tags: c#

```
    public Item(string Name, int Amount, double SizeInCubicMeters, int PriceInEURO, int CodeItem)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.CodeItem = CodeItem > 0 ? CodeItem : throw new Exception("The value cannot be negative.");
        this.Amount = Amount > 0 ? Amount: throw new Exception("The value cannot be negative.");
        this.SizeInCubicMeters = SizeInCubicMeters > 0 ? SizeInCubicMeters : 
            throw new Exception("The value cannot be negative.");
        this.PriceInEURO = PriceInEURO > 0 ? PriceInEURO : throw new Exception("The value cannot be negative.");




    }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? `if (!IsValidName(Name)) throw new ArgumentException();` метод IsValidName напишите самостоятельно

Comment: а можно без дополнительного метода?

Comment: Можно. В чем проблема?

Comment: Спасибо:) То есть в этом методе мы должны сказать что наше поле не должно быть null и нельзя ввести цифры?

Comment: Напишите там любые необходимые вам проверки

Comment: Если свойство Name может быть изменено после инициализации, то проверку лучше переместить из конструктора в сеттер свойства, а в конструкторе только устанавливать